# Iphone tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using below code for getting index number of the row. I want to get the Text of row. Please tell me, what modifications are required to get the text from each row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath{

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    detail.rowNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", (indexPath.row) ];
}
```

thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get cell with all its properties this way:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath{
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    detail.rowNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", (indexPath.row) ];
    detail.someLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Is this what you want? Text from selected cell?

Comment: thanx Condor! Actually I am new to ios, so would you please tell me where to add this code in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath{

    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    detail.rowNum.text = cellText;
}
```

Update ur code as above.

Comment: thanks "iamsult" you have made it easy for me ... Would you please tell me if there is any book from which i could learn IOS programming easily .... i am eager to learn it

Comment: If u got the exact answer u should upvote or accept it. Now coming to the book the iOS had been changed a lot. You better start with viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos guide by apple it will give u clear idea of the sdk and then u can go through the tutorials as required.        For beginners this is helpful http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: thnx, i have tried to vote up but for that 15 reputation is required.